# Many to many to many relationship query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I got 3 main table.

Table A
Table B
Table C

Table A has many to many relationships with Table B
so they have a pivot table ab

Table B has also many to many relationships with Table C
so they also have a pivot table bc

So because of this Table A has many to many through, relationship with Table C.

So what is the MySQL query if I wanted to get all rows of Table C that is related to Table A?

Answer (score 0):

You work backwards:

```
$tableAID = 1;

TableC::whereHas('tableB', function($q) use ($tableAID) {
    $q->whereHas('tableA', function($q) use ($tableAID) {
        $q->where('id', $tableAID);
    });
})->get();
```

Comment: This is my current solution but this is not ideal.

Comment: @AlvinPacot You could write raw SQL instead i suppose. Why is this not ideal? Is it because you want to `$tableA->tableC`?

Comment: Because whereHas is looping each column and I wanted a less loops or no loops as much as possible so yeah I guess I will write raw sql in the future.

Comment: @AlvinPacot What do you mean by looping each column?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the models well, `A->Bs->Cs;` should do the trick.